# Embed website as Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I'm basically trying to put all the functionality of this website: http://greenthumbweather.com/

into Facebook via the "website" platform.

I've started the app process in facebook and I entered the URL as website platform (attached image).

However, when I go to preview the "app", I just get a link to my website in the top right (attached image).

Do I have to recreate the entire functionality of the website within Facebook?  Or can I just port the functionality into a Facebook app?  I really would like users to be able to visit the website within Facebook, where it would grab their location information and customize my website based on their latitude/longitude.

Thanks for any help!

[image: app]
[image: settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can just port your website to facebook app but i think that depend on your desired output.  Your website can also be ported to a canvas app.

Comment: I'm wondering how to go about this.  I'm desiring the same output that is on my website, just within Facebook.  Thanks for any help.  I haven't found any good tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: You can also do that. It's just you are putting your website inside facebook iframe. I have done porting a gallery from a website and put it on facebook as facebook app for pages.